# Reusable SVG with different gradient colors

Tags: html, css, svg, gradient, linear-gradients

As per my requirement, I need shaped path in which I need to apply different gradient colors. Just for example here, I am taking a circle and trying to do the same.

Here is the code:

```css
.box--blue{
  fill: blue;
}

.box--red{
  fill: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <svg>
    <defs>
      <linearGradient id="Gradient2" x1="0" x2="0" y1="0" y2="1">
        <stop offset="0%" stop-color="transparent"/>
        <stop offset="100%" stop-color="blue"/>
      </linearGradient>
    </defs>
    <symbol id="gra2" viewbox="0 0 100 100">
  
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" fill="url(#Gradient2)" />
    </symbol>
</svg>
</div>


<div class="box box--red">
  <svg>
    <use xlink:href="#gra2"></use>
  </svg>
</div>

<div class="box box--blue">
  <svg>
    <use xlink:href="#gra2"></use>
  </svg>
</div>
```

### Requirement:

I need those two gradient shapes with different colors by reusing the available SVG.

Browser support: IE10+, chrome and Firefox.

Note: I don't want to hardcode each color related gradient under the SVG. The Gradient color should be able to inherit. That is how I can reuse the SVG, IMO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you want is not possible.

The nearest I think you can get is use the special colour `currentColor` to pass the current value of CSS `color` into the symbol.  You can pass it to the symbol, but not the gradient.  So you would need to use it to color one circle.  Then put a gradient on top of that.  However, in this solution, the circle obviously can't be partially transparent as in your example.

```css
.box--blue {
  color: blue;
}

.box--red {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <svg>
    <defs>
      <linearGradient id="Gradient2" x1="0" x2="0" y1="0" y2="1">
        <stop offset="0%" stop-color="white"/>
        <stop offset="100%" stop-color="transparent"/>
      </linearGradient>
    </defs>
    <symbol id="gra2" viewbox="0 0 100 100">
      <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" fill="currentColor" />
      <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" fill="url(#Gradient2)" />
    </symbol>
</svg>
</div>


<div class="box box--red">
  <svg>
    <use xlink:href="#gra2"></use>
  </svg>
</div>

<div class="box box--blue">
  <svg>
    <use xlink:href="#gra2"></use>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome, very clever I should say.. I thought the same that it is not possible but at last you showed the way. Hope this works in real scenario. Thanks :)